# How to use google translate by sending a http request

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, google-translate

I captured http request from google translate (google search page) .

And i tried to do it using python with a http post request

And it failed with 404 status code.

Request text file : https://mega.nz/file/5C4QmYpZ#CgS5kQSRnQ1_NrDjYKLoFlM_gM3cNkUvfu-TZShpElc

my code :

```
import requests as req 

url = "https://www.google.com/async/translate?"

query = {"vet": "12ahUKEwj0kbyq9drqAhX27XMBHVzSDZAQqDgwAHoECAQQIQ..i","ei": "RRMVX7TbHfbbz7sP3KS3gAk","client": "opera","hs": "HG5","yv": "3"}

pload = {"async": "translate","sl":"auto","tl":"en","st":"hola","id":"1595216804027","qc":"true","ac":"true","_id":"tw-async-translate","_pms":"s","_fmt":"pc"}

res = req.post(url , params=query , data=pload )

print(res.text)

print(res.status_code)
```

**Somebody help me with this**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Google API Client:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
service = build('translate', 'v2', developerKey=APIKEY)

# use the service
inputs = text_file.readlines()
outputs = service.translations().list(source='en', target='fr', q=inputs).execute()
# print outputs
for input, output in zip(inputs, outputs['translations']):
  print("{0} -> {1}".format(input, output['translatedText']))
```

Comment: is there any way without api key ?

Comment: With the Google's one, no. However the key is free. Is this a problem?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the "vet" query string parameter is shortened, you can tell by  the two dots in Q..i
Also, you shouldn't just copy the query string data and payload from whatever you found in inspect element. You should try to reverse engineer the module that is behind sending the /async/translate request and find out how to properly determine parameters and values. That's actually what I'm working on right now haha...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).